# Are there microcontrollers with Bluetooth and CANBUS unit?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, can-bus

I'm looking for Microntroller (something like ARM Cortex M4) that will have Bluetooth and CAN support. ST has a lot of Bluetooth or CAN chips, but none has both together...

We would like to avoid two chip design...

Thanks.

Comment: Actually this should probably have been asked at the electronics site https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

[ESP32](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/socs/esp32) has both Bluetooth and CAN (they call it "Two-Wire Automotive Interface").

Here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: Is that really a MCU though? And not a module with external controllers? Also "two-wire automoative interface" smells skunky, like something non-compliant. There's no royalties involved in CAN as far as I know, so why not call it that.

Comment: @Lundin The modules are well known among hobbyists, but I am talking about the chip itself.

Comment: So the MCU would be Tensilica? You should link to the MCU manufacturer since the OP is looking for a MCU.

Comment: @Lundin I linked to the manufacturer. Tensilica is a core vendor, just like ARM.

Comment: I added a link to the datasheet for clarity.

Comment: ESP seems interesting. Can ESP32 be considered as "serious embeeded platform" for industrial grade development ? I have no experience with it...

Comment: @bully44 I guess it depends on your definition of serious. NXP and Renesas suggested by Lundin literally own the automotive market. I think ESP32 is aimed more at IoT. On the other hand, ESP32 has a very good development framework, which can help you get up and running fast.

Comment: @bully44 What's the application?

Answer (score 1):

I did some brief research:

- NXP [KW39](https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/bluetooth-low-energy/kw39-38-37-32-bit-bluetooth-5-0-long-range-mcus-with-can-fd-and-lin-bus-options-arm-cortex-m0-plus-core:KW39-38-37). This would be an M0+.
- Renesas [RA4W1](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/ra-cortex-m-mcus/ra4w1-low-energy-single-chip-32-bit-microcontrollers-48mhz-bluetooth-50?) is a M4.

Silicon Labs have lots of Bluetooth products but I didn't find one with a CAN controller - I didn't look that carefully though.